# Extracting list of values from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[7,8,9,0]])
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  7  8  9  0
```

issuing

```
df.iloc[1,3]
```

returns the value on 1,3; this is, 0

but

```
df.iloc[np.array([1,1]),np.array([1,3])]
```

returns

```
   1  3
1  8  0
1  8  0
```

but I want

[8,0]

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy indexing - so convert DataFrame to 2d numpy array first:

```
print (df.to_numpy()[np.array([1,1]),np.array([1,3])].tolist())
[8, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in easier way:

- Use `loc[index,columns]` i-e, pass index and list of columns.

```
print(df.loc[1,[1,3]].to_list())
>> [8, 0]
```